# Cases where EffectiveUser email is null

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this code to store user email in properties:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    menu.addItem('Enable add-on', 'authorizer');
    menu.addToUi();
  } 
  else { 
    var USEREMAIL = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('USER_EMAIL', USEREMAIL);
}}
```

However according to logs, there are many errors, where for some reason it appears to be null in many functions that load USER_EMAIL property:

What are the possible cases where a null might be saved into that property?

Just to let you know, I get a lot of nulls from different users:
[image]

Thank you!